# What is the right version of MySQL Workbench to connect to a mysql 5.6 db?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I downloaded the latest version of Mysql-workbench but it does not communicate properly with a 5.6 environment. 
Which one of the archived versions should i install?

Adding the commented line inside the loop makes the whole procedure fail:

```
while i <= N 
    do 
    -- set Statement = ''; 
    set i = i+1; 
       end while;
```

Comment: MySQL/5.6 is not that old. What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: i am trying to installing a procedure (that i installed correctly locally) but i get the error:   Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: i modified the procedure to a minimal version and i made it work but if i add the necessary commands inside the while loop i get error: for example removing the comment from this piece of code makes the while procedure fail:                                              
               while i <= N do 
  -- set Statement = '';
  set i = i+1;
  end while;

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Perhaps you're making too many assumptions. Also, if there's a bug in current Workbench version that doesn't mean that older versions will not have it. I suggest you try your code in any other client (e.g. HeidiSQL or good old command-line). Additionally, if you're sharing code here it's better if it's self-contained so we can try it ourselves—a tiny fragment that can't even run is not as helpful.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench 8.0.18 (that means: the latest at this timepoint) supports MySQL servers 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0. See also the [product platform page](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html).

The error you get is totally unrelated to the server or WB versions. Looks like you ran a query without reading the results. It could even be WB is guilty here as it is usually taking care to read results from a query. Try running your code in the MySQL shell to see if it is actually correct. If that works correctly then file a [bug report against MySQL Workbench](https://bugs.mysql.com).